# How can I download the particular file which is uploaded using carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Hi I am using Ruby 2 and Rails 4. I am uploading a pdf file and its stored in `public/uploads/contact/file/15/abc.pdf` because I am using CarrierWave, and in my file_uploader.rb the below code is written.

```
def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
 end
```

Now I want to download the same file which I uploaded. How can I download that  file? Please share with me if anyone has any idea. I am adding my code below.

Showing picture what I want to do exactly. Choosing a file upload it and then download it.
[image]

My codes are:

downloads_form.html.erb

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-responsive">
        <tbody>
            <%= form_tag create_form_path,  multipart: true  do |f| %>
            <tr>                
                <td>ABC</td>
                <td><%= file_field_tag "contact[file]",  class: "form-control" %></td>
                <td><%= submit_tag 'Upload' %></td>
                <td><%= link_to "Download", static_pages_downloadform_pdf_path %></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>               
                <td>DEF</td>
                <td><%= file_field_tag "contact[file]",  class: "form-control" %></td>
                <td><%= submit_tag 'Upload' %></td>
                <td><%= link_to "Download", static_pages_downloadform_pdf_path %></td>
            </tr>
            <% end %> 

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

static_pages_controller.rb

```
  def create_form
    @form_downup = Contact.new(contact_params)
    if @form_downup.save
      redirect_to :back
    else
      render downloads_form_path
    end
  end

  def downloadform_pdf

  end

 private
    def contact_params
       params.require(:contact).permit(:file)

    end
```

routes.rb

```
  match '/downloads_form', to: 'static_pages#downloads_form', via: 'get', as: :downloads_form
  match '/create_form', to: 'static_pages#create_form', via: 'post', as: :create_form     
  get "static_pages/downloadform_pdf"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by this way.

```
def downloadform_pdf

    file_type=params[:file_name]

    contact = Contact.find_by_name(file_type)
    actual_file_name=contact.file.to_s
    file = File.join(Rails.root, 'public',actual_file_name)
    send_file(file, filename: 'My-Form.pdf', type: 'application/pdf')

  end
```

View:

```
<%= form_tag create_form_path,  multipart: true  do |f| %> 
   <td><%= text_field_tag "contact[name]", nil, value: "G_form", class: "form-control", :readonly => true %></td>
   <td><%= file_field_tag "contact[file]",  class: "form-control" %></td>
   <td><%= submit_tag 'Upload' %></td>
   <td><%= link_to "Download", static_pages_downloadform_pdf_path(:file_name => "G_form") %></td> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can't begin to express my gratitude for this.  Took me a couple days trying to figure this out! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**I am adding  a example, by looking on this you can solve your problem**

In your view =>

```
<%= link_to "click here to download", signed_feeds_pdf_path(:feed_image_path => feed_image.feedimage.path), target: '_self' %>
```

In your controller =>

```
     def pdf    
        file_name = params[:feed_image_path].split('/').last
        @filename ="#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/feed_image/feedimage/#{file_name}"
        send_file(@filename ,
          :type => 'application/pdf/docx/html/htm/doc',
          :disposition => 'attachment')           
      end
```